# Find minimum number of binary-decimals for a given input -n.

Tags: binary, decimal

**A number is called as binary-decimal if all the digits in the number should be either ‘1’ or ‘0’. Any number can be written as a sum of binary-decimals. Our task is to find the minimum number of binary-decimals to represent a number.**

**Input**  : 32 
**Output** : 10 11 11

**Input**  : 120
**Output** : 10 110

What could be an efficient solution to this?

Answer (score 5):

take for example

54321 the answer is

11111

11110

11100

11000

10000

so consider it as a m*n matrix where m is maximum value of the digit in given number and n is number of digits. Then fill the columns with number of 1's equal to the value of digit corresponding to that column and rest with 0's.

```
        #include<iostream>

        using namespace std;
        int max(int arr[],int c)
        {
            int max=arr[0];
            for(int i=1;i<c;i++){
                if(arr[i]>max){
                    max=arr[i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
        int main() {
            int n,x,c=0,i=0,j=0;
            cin>>n;
            x=n;
            while(n!=0){
                n=n/10;
                c++;
            }
            int *a=new int[c];

            while(x!=0){
                a[i]=x%10;
                x=x/10;
                i++;
            }
            int r=max(a,c);
            int ans[r][c];
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
                {
                    if(a[c-i-1]!=0){
                        ans[j][i]=1;
                        a[c-i-1]--;
                    }
                    else
                        ans[j][i]=0;
                }
            }
            for(i=0;i<r;i++){
                for(j=0;j<c;j++){
                    cout<<ans[i][j];
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }

            }
```

Comment: This is the best solution I have seen for this question so far. Good one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using DP. May not be as good as the previous one. But this could be another approach.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
class Deci_binary
{
public static void main(String ars[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    Deci_binary Db=new Deci_binary();
    Db.deci_binary(sc.nextInt());
}
public void deci_binary(int input)
{
    String input_string=input+"";
    int length=input_string.length();
    ArrayList<Integer> combination=combination(length);
    ArrayList dp[]=new ArrayList[input+1];
    ArrayList<Integer> empty=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dp[0]=empty;
    int combination_size=combination.size();
    for(int i=1;i<=input;i++)
    {
        dp[i]=null;
        for(int j=0;j<combination_size;j++)
        {
            int combination_get=combination.get(j);
            if(i>=combination_get)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> previous=new ArrayList<Integer>(dp[i-combination_get]);
                previous.add(combination_get);
                dp[i]=min(dp[i],previous);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dp[input]);

}
public ArrayList<Integer> min(ArrayList<Integer> first,ArrayList<Integer> second)
{
    if(first==null)
    {
        return second;
    }
    else{
        int first_size=first.size();
        int second_size=second.size();
        if(first_size<second_size)
        {
            return first;
        }
        else{
            return second;
        }
    }
}
public ArrayList<Integer> combination(int number)//this will give all the combinations of binary number having x number of digits
{

    int last_number=(int)Math.pow(2,number);
    ArrayList<Integer> combination=new ArrayList<Integer>(last_number-1);
    for(int i=1;i<last_number;i++)
    {
        combination.add(Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(i)));            
    }
    return combination;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution could be return the highest digit from the number.
For example :
The answer to 82734 is

11111

11111

10111

10101

10100

10100

10100

10000

Below is a c++ solution for this.

```
int solve(int n) {
    string n_str = to_string(n);
    return *max_element(n_str.begin(),n_str.end()) - '0';
}
```